# Hide instances outside of area

Tags: instances

If I make a grid of 10x10 instances, and then draw a shape, how can I make the instances only appear within that shape?

Instances are just made from collection instances. Nothing fancy, no arrays, no scatters, no particles. yet.

In other software, I'd use a 'kill' element that would destroy particles or references outside the the 'kill' object, but I can't seem to find the Blender equivalent

Comment: Add more details to your question.How are you making the grid? Are you using an array, Geometry nodes, Particle system (like hairs), duplicates?

Comment: Hi, Andrew .. Blender has many possible equivalents.. which ones to recommend will depend on how your instances were created, and represented in the scene, and how you want to use the result. Please help us narrow this down, by providing those details.

Comment: ok question is updated

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, are you talking about camera culling?

Comment: No. I'm surprised that the blender community don't know about kill boundaries - Objects that fall outside of a defined area are destroyed (never instanced or rendered)

Comment: For people looking for something more advanced in case of a complex geometry: [Is it possible to scatter points on the outside surface of a group of instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/300094/60486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup and goal is not exactly clear from your wording, but if you mean you have a bunch of objects in a Collection, and you'd like to delete or hide the ones that falls outside the volume of a certain object, you can do that with a simple *Geometry Nodes* setup like below. In the scene I have a 3D-array of individual spheres (simply duplicated with <kbd>Shift + D</kbd>), all in a collection called *OBJECTS*, which is hidden. Then you have your "kill" object, in this case a torus, which hosts the Geometry Nodes modifier. We hid the *OBJECTS* collection because we're gonna re-create it inside Geometry Nodes—we need to do that because since Geometry Nodes is just a modifier, it can only affect the object it is being hosted on.

In the Geometry Nodes setup, you simply send rays (`Raycast`) from each instance origin (`Position`) to the torus' mesh, and compare those position vectors to the *normal*s (direction) of the faces the rays hit. If they align (*face the same direction*—`Dot Product`), it means the instances are inside the volume, if they don't align (`Not`) it means they're outside, and can be deleted (`Delete Geometry`):

[image]

Comment: This is the right interpretation of what i'm asking for - Being able to remove objects that are outside of a boundry

Answer (score 2):

Kuboa's answer is exactly what I needed, but as of 3.5.1, Raycast needs to look a little different. Also, you don't need the dot product. All you want is to see if Raycast returns a nonzero value. To do this, simply connect *Hit Normal* to a *Boolean Math* node (set to *Not*), which will interpolate the values to a boolean value. Based on this behavior, I assume Raycast returns $0$ if no intersection is detected. Also, if you use a direction vector value of $(0,0,-1)$, you can put a single plane under the object and use that as a trim object for grass, etc.

[image]